# Kendo Grid Column bound Dropdown Row wise binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, grid, kendo-ui

I am facing one issue on kendo grid.

I have Kendo grid in that i have one dropdown which is loading on the basis of `ViewData["abc"]` using editor template and also having 2 fields such as Arrival Date and Departure Date.

My issue is that i want to load dropdown on the basis of Arrival date and Departure date, so in this case every dropdown having diffrent values. so how can i achive this?

Here are the sample code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ManageRequests()
{
    try
    {
        var result = _partialControlService.PopulateDropdowns();
        PopulateDropdowns(result);
    }
    return View();
}

public void PopulateDropdowns(Model.ManageRequestDropdowns model)
{
    if (ViewData["hotels"] != null)
    {
        List<ClientHotelViewModel> objhotel = new List<ClientHotelViewModel>();
        objhotel = model.Hotels
               .Select(e => new ClientHotelViewModel
               {
                   HotelIDPK = e.HotelIDPK,
                   HotelName = e.HotelName
               }).OrderBy(e => e.HotelName).ToList<ClientHotelViewModel>();

        if (objhotel != null && objhotel.Count() > 0)
            objClientHotelViewModel.AddRange(objhotel);

        ViewData["hotels"] = objClientHotelViewModel.OrderBy(x => x.HotelIDPK);
    }
}
```

EditorTemplate:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("Hotel")
            .DataValueField("HotelIDPK")
            .DataTextField("HotelName")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["hotels"])
)
```

ManageHotel.cshtml:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<HotelRooming.ViewModels.ManageRequestViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ArrivalDate).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Arrivaldate" }).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.DepartureDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Hotel).Width(150).ClientTemplate("#=Hotel.HotelName#").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "HotelNames" }).Filterable(false);
    })
)
```

Model:

```
public class ManageRequestViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Check-in Date")]
    public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Check-out Date")]
    public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }

    [UIHint("ClientHotel")]
    [DisplayName("Hotel")]
    public ClientHotelViewModel Hotel { get; set; }    
}
```

Any help will be great appreciated.